# Protractor: how to tick a checkbox

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, protractor

I have the markup like the one below.

```
<label class="styled-checkbox ng-binding">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkedAll" ng-click="checkAllItems($event)" ng-disabled="disabledAll" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <div class="styled-checkbox__box">
</div>Select All</label>
```

Using Protractor I was able to check the state of the checkbox (unticked) by:

```
expect(element(by.model('checkedAll')).isSelected()).toBe(false);
```

But I failed to tick that checkbox. Generally I get the error that the element is not visible. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the error and the code you used for ticking the check-box?

Comment: The latest command I used was simple: element(by.model('checkedAll')).click();

This line (24) caused error: 
Message:     ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
 at Array.forEach (native)

Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/user/prj/spec.js:24:34)

Comment: Are you sure the `input` is not hidden? Looking at the mark-up, you may have this `div` with the `styled-checkbox__box` class shown instead.

Comment: yes, indeed the reason was that the element is really hidden (i thought it's my bad locator). thanks

Comment: Guys, please help. Have similar problem, but I don`t catch the idea. How the element could be hidden?
<div class="checkbox">
          <input ng-model="model.user.isKeepSignedIn" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
          <label for="checkbox">Keep me signed in</label>
 </div>
and I'm using this locator:
const isKeepSignedIn = element(by.model('model.user.isKeepSignedIn'));